# No margin after </ul> tag in IE7 and IE8. IE9, FF, Chrome are ok

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have some simple code:

```
<h3>An h3 header</h3>
<ul>
 <li>More stuff</li>
 <li>other stuff</li>
 <li>Still other stuff
   <ul>
      <li>inner stuff1</li>
      <li>inner stuff2</li>
      <li>inner stuff3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Another list item</li>
  <li>some More stuff</li>
  <li>another other stuff</li>
  <li>text other stuff
    <ul>
       <li>other inner stuff1</li>
       <li>other inner stuff2</li>
       <li>other inner stuff3</li>
       <li>other inner stuff4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>This h3 tag no has no top margin at all in IE7 and IE8, the above h3 tag has margin</h3>
```

The code renders fine in IE9, FF, and Chrome. Meaning there is margin between the last h3 tag and the final /ul tag. Any thoughts? There is a global css reset file which zeros out everything.

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ is the reset file

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ee3129;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
 li {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
ul li {
  list-style: outside disc;
  margin: 0 0 6px 16px;
  line-height: 14px;
  
}
ul li ul {
  margin: 6px 0 0 0;
}
ul li ul li {
  padding-left: 14px;
  background: url(../images/bg_li.png) no-repeat 0 center;
  list-style: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you run your code through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?

If you have invalid HTML, IE may revert to quirks mode regardless of the DOCTYPE and therefore ingnore your css margins on ul's. Also please make sure that the DOCTYPE the first thing in the document (no spaces), or IE will ignore it.

Comment: I ran it through the validator and did find a few errors which I corrrected, but it didn't change the problem. Thanks for the suggestion though! I'm glad I was able to clean it up a bit.

Comment: What does your DOCTYPE look like? Update your code with the full page code.

Comment: I can't use full code - it's a high end client site and do not want to put it out. The DOCTYPE is: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> (not my choice) But I did find something interesting. When I removed all the imgs - the margin was correct on IE8.